# Calling controller to populate accordion item on expand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery

In a rails 3 app using Jquery and JqueryUI, I'm rendering a partial to display an accordion list of Items. I wish to call a controller action (let's call it the `Item#get_details` action) to retrieve additional details via a web service about the Item upon the expansion of the appropriate accordion component.

The collection of items passed into the partial contains a description and an item number, as such:

```
render :partial => 'candidates' , :collection => @candidates
#Candidates is a list of hashes, each hash containing keys "Desc" and "id_number"
```

Each pass through the partial renders markup which jqueryUI renders as an accordion section, as below:

```
<h3><%= candidate[:desc] %>
<div id="candidate_details">
</div>
```

What is the best practice for binding a controller call to the `<h3>` which will retrieve details and populate the "candidate_details" div upon activation of the accordion item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd close that `<h3>`. Then use a data attribute on the `<h3>` to hold the `id_number`:

```
<h3 data-id="<%= candidate[:id_number] %>"><%= candidate[:desc] %></h3>
<div id="candidate_details"></div>
```

Sounds like you want your accordion to start out with everything closed so you'd use something like this to bind the accordion:

```
// Adjust these options to match your needs of course...
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    active: false
});
```

The `collapsible` option allows all the panels to be closed at once, the `autoHeight` setting allows the panels to resize to fit their content, and the `active` setting starts them all out closed.

Then, you could use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a click handler to the `<h3>`s that will remove itself after its first activation. That click handler can dig out the `data-id` value and do an AJAX call to get the content for the corresponding `<div>`:

```
$('#accordion').find('h3').one('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).next().load('/some/path/' + id);
});
```

Then your controller would use the `id` to look up the necessary content and send it back as a little blob of HTML.

Demo of the jQuery-UI side: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BhJYv/

Comment: Thanks for this...This seems simple and straightforward to me, I appreciate your help.